# Dreamweaver: having an image or button change after it is clicked on

Tags: image, button, dreamweaver, rollover-effect

Hi I am using Dreamweaver and trying to get an image or button to change after it is clicked on. Essentially, I want an image to say follow before it is clicked on and say unfollow after it is clicked on like happens on Twitter, Quora etc.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean an active link? (a:active{ })

Comment: I just want to add that I am a complete novice. But I don't think I mean active link because I want the viewer to remain on the same page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Spencer: Are you using a JavaScript framework (e.g. jQuery or mootools)? You could add or replace a class for the button when it is clicked so that it'll have a different style to the button in its default state.

**Update**: Here's some sample code to get you started (see it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/5HqFw/) --

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>questions/4527859</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#button').click(function() {
            $(this).toggleClass("clicked");
        });
    });
</script>

<style type="text/css">
    #button {        
        border: 1px solid green;
        display: block;
        padding: 5px;
        text-align: center;
        width: 100px;
    }
    .default {
        background-color: white;
        color: green;
    }
    .clicked {
        background-color: green;
        color: white;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>

<p><a href="#" id="button" class="default">Button!</a></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am a complete novice and am not using any JavaScript tools

Comment: @Spencer: Ok; do yourself a huge favour by going to http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works and learning about the jQuery framework. There are also http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials to take you further.